# correcting computed table cell height by programmatically scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am computing the height of my tavleview cells individually myself.

While this works well when I scroll, sometimes when the table appears it looks wrong.

Then if I scroll up and down it looks correct.

Therefore I need to programmatically scroll the table.

Now the problem is that sometimes I only have 3 lines so I cannot scroll programmatically - but manually one can "scroll" the view even if there are no more cells. In this case I still need to "scroll" the view programmatically since this corrects the computation of the tablecell height,

So this code does not work:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0];
[self.theTable scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                              animated:YES];
```

So the question is, how can I scroll the view programmatically?

****EDIT****
I checked the computed heights and they are all correct - even after scrolling they compute to exactly the same as when initially displayed.

So I gave the frame a red background to see the difference between the display right after view did appear compared to after the scrolling.

And in fact the frames ALL after the viewDidAppear are of the same (wrong) height, which is not the height with which they are set like this:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];

//                              x     y   width height
float h = expectedLabelSize.height;
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(    8.0, 10.0,  20.0, 20.0)];
[t1 setFrame:CGRectMake(          40.0,  4.0, 280.0, h)]; //total width 320
[t1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[t2 setFrame: CGRectMake(        235.0, h+4, 85.0, 15.0)];
NSLog(@"-layoutSubviews--> h:%f w:%f",h,expectedLabelSize.width);
```

}

After the scrolling the height is computed to exactly the same value AND now finally the frame has the height as assigned here.

Comment: Why don't you try to fix the real problem? Computing individual cell heights can be done.

Comment: Because the computation is correct - since it works when I scroll. All I need to do is scroll the view down programmatically or somehow force all the cells to be recomputed. ReloadData does not trigger that.

Comment: Did you try calling `[self.tableView beginUpdates]` immediately followed by `[self.tableView endUpdates]` ? That should trigger a recalculation of the cell heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewWillAppear`:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: unfortunately does not work - the only thing that works so far is to move the table cells once they appeared all over the top so they have to come back and then seem to calculate correctly....

Comment: @user387184: You probably have to show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` methods.

Comment: I will - just need to prepare it since it is quite complicated and calls several other methods... Thanks!

Comment: So I added the code and the explanation what is actually happening above....there seems to be a problem with the layout of the iPhone not with my computation of the height

Comment: I ended up just adding the height of a line and hope it works in all my cases - the cell is higher but it looks OK initially and after scrolling. Anyway I did not find an explanation for this.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the exact same problem with resizing a cell dynamically to accomodate the contents of a UITextView. I ended up using the free Sensible TableView framework, which amongst many other things, automatically calculates the height for all my cells.